# Raphael: Set Line Color

Tags: javascript, raphael

I am using the Raphael JS vector library and I cannot get a line (path) that I am drawing to change colors. Hopefully it's just something stupid I did.

```
var blue_one = paper.path ("M205 205L300 300");
blue_one.attr ("stroke-width", "3");
blue_one.attr ("fill", "#0000FF");
```

I have also tried fill values of "#00F", "blue", "0000FF", and "00F".

Answer (score 17, accepted):

This is what you want to set.

```
blue_one.attr ("stroke", "#0000FF");
```

For a full listing of the properties, see the [Specification](http://www.w3.org/TR/SVG/painting.html) or the [Raphael Documentation](http://dmitrybaranovskiy.github.io/raphael/reference.html#Element.attr)

Answer (score 0):

Can be written simply in one line like this.

```
var blue_one = paper.path ("M205 205L300 300").attr({stroke:'#0000FF'});
```